# Unable to delete an item from the database using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, database, mongoose, ejs

I was trying to add this delete functionality in the blog webiste such that when the user clicks the delete button, it would delete that particular item from the database, but i ran into some bug.

This is my home.ejs:

```
 <%- include("partials/header"); -%>
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p> <%= startingContent %> </p>


  <%  posts.forEach(function(post){ %>

    <h1><%=post.title%></h1>
    <p>
    <%=post.content.substring(0, 100) + " ..."%>
    <a href="/posts/<%=post._id%>">Read More</a>
    </p>


    <% }) %>

<%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

This is the post.ejs (the page for each journal entry, when someone clicks read more, it sends the user to that particular post's page)

```
<%- include("partials/header"); -%>

  <h1><%=title%></h1>
  <p><%=content%></p>

  <form action="/posts/delete" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-small" name="button" type="submit" value="<%=post._id%>">Delete</button>
  </form>

<%- include("partials/footer"); -%>
```

and here is my app.js:

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const homeStartingContent = "Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing.";
const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.";
const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero.";

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/blogDB");

const postSchema = {
  title: String,
  content: String
};

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);

app.get("/", function(req, res){

  Post.find({}, function(err, posts) {
    res.render("home", {
      startingContent: homeStartingContent,
      posts: posts
      });
  });

});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about", {aboutContent: aboutContent});
});

app.get("/contact", function(req, res){
  res.render("contact", {contactContent: contactContent});
});

app.get("/compose", function(req, res){
  res.render("compose");
});

app.post("/compose", function(req, res){
  const post = new Post ({
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  });

  post.save(function(err){

   if (!err){
     res.redirect("/");
   }

  });

});

app.get("/posts/:postId", function(req, res){
  const requestedPostId = req.params.postId;

  Post.findOne({_id: requestedPostId}, function(err, post) {
    res.render("post", {
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content
    });
  });

});

app.post("/delete", function (req, res) {
  const idDelete = req.body.button;

  Post.findByIdAndRemove(idDelete, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Deleted Sucessfully");
    }
    res.redirect("/");
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

But the trouble i am having is that, the server refuses to recognise "post._id" that i used for the button value in post.ejs.
[image]

If i remove the button value, the console log shows "Deleted sucessfully" and i also get redirected to the home page but it doesnt delete the post at all.

this is how my post page should look (but as i said, it doesnt really work, if i click delete i just get redirected to the home page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You either need to pass `_id` when while rendering `post.ejs` or complete post object. You're just passing only `title` and `content`.